# Java: Obtain the Subset of an Array that meet a criteria

Tags: java, arrays, java-me, vectorization

I have an an array of arrays.
`float[][] Test`

For example

```
  {  {433801.000f,335601.000f,5},
     {433821.000f,335631.000f,5},
     {433811.000f,335671.000f,5}  };
```

How can I get the subset of this array (or array of arrays), where the values meet a criteria.

For example where `Test[i][0] > 40000` and `Test[i][1] + Test[i][2] < 350000`

I can obviously iterate through the list. But this will be very slow when the array is of huge magnitude.

How would I do this in a vectorised manner.

Im also using JavaME if this causes any limitations. But a JavaSE Solution would be great insight too and hopefully work in JavaME.

Comment: I don't think you can explicitly do vectorised computations like this in JavaSE or JavaME.  The JVM *might* vectorise some calculations, but they'll probably have to be very simple and I don't think your arrays have a layout that would allow this.

Comment: Cheers for the answers. I'll restructure a bit ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do it without iterating unless you store more information about the data.

I would suggest that in addition to storing the full data, for every new record, you test it with your condition and if it's true, save the item reference in another array (well, `Vector` is better for both of these unless storage is *really* tight).

Then when you want all the items matching the condition, just look up all the references in the second "array".  This is roughly how some database queries are optimised.  The lookup cost is reduced at the expense of higher insertion and storage cost.

Comment: I think there is no `ArrayList` in JavaME.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I did JavaME - I meant `Vector` (edited to show that).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think iterating over the entire array and testing those conditions is as fast as any other way. The upside is that it's very simple to implement. How big do you expect that array to be ? If, in the worst case, it'll have just a few thousand rows, you'll be ok :) .

Comment: So there is no vectorised method? This would greatly increase speed. A few thousand records yes. But this code will be run a lot. Possibly every few seconds.

Comment: What is a “vectorized method?” If you want to know which elements of an array fulfill a certain requirement you have to look at each element of the array—unless you use an indexing method as described by @andrewmu above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vectorization/info "Vectorization refers to a programming paradigm where functions operate on whole arrays in one go. This affords benefits in terms of function calls, memory access, parallelization and code expressiveness. Some programming languages, such as MATLAB, optimised to give the best performance when vectorized."

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid a linear scan is to store your data in a sorted manner.  Using some kind of tree structure is probably the way forward for quick look up.  This means not storing your data in arrays of arrays, which may violate your memory requirements, but that is the tradeoff.